# Developer Story: Text overlap between Matches and "Finish your profile" sidebar sections on back

Tags: bug, developer-story, user-interface

When I press <kbd>Go back one page</kbd> on Firefox and go to my story page the two aforementioned sections overlap. More precisely, the "Finish your profile" sidebar section remains docked at the top, while you scroll upwards, until you reach the Options section. Then it gets fixed by itself.

The **precondition** for this bug is to have scrolled downwards just a bit before going to a new page. Here is a visual depiction:

[image]